# readFile cause "Could not fulfill resource requirements of job"

Tags: java, scala, apache-flink

I have s3 with terabytes of data, separated to small files less than 5 mb.
I try to use flink to process them.
I create source with next code.

```
var inputFormat = new TextInputFormat(null);
inputFormat.setNestedFileEnumeration(true);
return streamExecutionEnvironment.readFile(inputFormat, "s3://name/");
```

But used memory growing up to limit, and job killed, and not scheduled again with error:

```
Could not fulfill resource requirements of job
```

Without data in sink.

On small set of data it works fine.

How I can read files without using too much memory?
Thanks.

same behaviour with:

```
env.fromSource( FileSource.forRecordStreamFormat(
                                new TextLineFormat(),
                                new Path("s3://name/")
                        )
                        .monitorContinuously(Duration.ofMillis(10000L))
                        .build(),
                WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(),
                "MySourceName"
        )
```

Comment: I'm wondering what you mean by "Without data in sink."

Comment: no data in output stream

Comment: It looks to me like passing null to `TextLineFormat(null)` shouldn't work. Can you try this with a valid character set name, or use the default via `TextLineFormat()`?

Comment: it mistake, null not change behavior

Comment: "Could not fulfill resource requirements of job" is produced when the cluster doesn't have enough task slots available to satisfy the requested parallelism. It sounds like you have underprovisioned the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

The `FileSource` is the preferred way to ingest data from files. It should be able to handle the sort of scale you are talking about.

[docs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/connectors/datastream/filesystem/)

[javadocs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/api/java/org/apache/flink/connector/file/src/FileSource.html)

Comment: I did update the question

Answer (score 0):

`setQueueLimit` on kinesis producer solved my problem https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/connectors/datastream/kinesis/#backpressure